# facebook misconfigure login android app

Tags: android, facebook

I developed an android app that has a facebook authentication.
The problem is that when i publish the application on the market and a user install the application and wants to login, he recieve a message from facebook that says "the application is missconfigured for facebook".

In order to publish my application on market i signed the application with a keystore.
The next step was to put the hash key in facebook developer console.

These are the steps for signing the application:

1) On my local computer i generated a .keystore file using this command:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

2) From eclipse i exported the application into an .apk file using the keystore file generated on step 1.

3) I uploaded the file on GooglePlay and published.

On my local computer and my tablet this problem does not reproduce. I tried to install on an android phone and the problem does reproduce.

Comment: Not sure if you've done this, but did you update (or add a new) keyhash to your facebook app with the new keystore that you generated? See step 5 in the getting started guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Answer (score 0):

The key hash that you put on the dashboard is your debug key.  By signing with your own key to upload to Google play, you need to take the key hash of the keystore that you used to sign the app and put that into your dashboard.